# How to "attach" a UITableViewCell to a TextView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I'm looking to make something like the To: field in Apples *Mail* app. Basically I want a UITableViewCell to stick to the top of a TextView. Actually it is not a necessity that it be a UITableViewCell, as long as I can stick a label, a text field and a button to the top, just as in the *Mail* composer.

I've tried to put these things on a scroll view, but couldn't figure that out.

Any help is appreciated :)

PS. I know of Three20, but I would much more like to figure out how to make this To: field lookalike myself, with my own code and no dependencies.

Comment: I think Mail does it by compositing everything into a `UIScrollView` then adjusting its content height based on the text view's content height (and making the text view non-scrollable).

Comment: @BoltClock, Actually it could've been an answer. I would upvote.

Comment: How would one "composite everything into a UIScrollView"?

Comment: Never mind. I wrapped my head around the scroll view and figured it out. As far as I understand, this is indeed how Apple has done it.

Comment: UITextView _is_ already a UIScrollView, so it shouldn't be necessary to wrap an additional scrollview around it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a table view and the view in the footer of the table view.